# How to set values to gridview textbox from javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

i have gridview with following itemtemplate

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>'
 </asp:TextBox>

<asp:LinkButton href="#modal-dialog1" ID="href_Score" role="button" data-toggle="modal"
runat="server" class="icon-photon comment_alt2_stroke" OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("javascript:return GetScores(this,\"{0}\")", Eval("ExceptionID")) %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>

</ItemTemplate>
```

one text box is there inside gridview and one link button also to popup the text box data.I am able to pop up the data.

In pop up window i am having another text box ,once data filled to this text box on clicking click me button of popup window, i need to assign pop up text box values back to the gridview text box.

Here is my popup div(which is created using javascript function)

```
<div id="modal-dialog1" class="modal hide fade">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" id="btnCloseModal" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h3>Score Detail</h3>
                    <br />                    
                    <span style="color: #4F81BD">
                        <br />
                        * Use as a finding ONLY .</span>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>Scores</h4>
                    <input type="text" name="AddComments" value=""/>
                    <button onclick="return myFunction()">Click me</button> 
                    <hr />                                              
                </div>
            </div>
```

i want to set the text box value back to the gridview inside  myFunction() function pls help me? how can i set values to gridview inside javascript function?

Comment: Post your javascript code

Comment: @Satindersingh i don't tried anything inside myFunction() ,not having any idea to set values to gridview through javascript\jquery

Comment: Can you share the code to open the popup?

Comment: @Rahul Singh: hi, i am just caliing a webmethod(which executes an stored proc)  which will return above mentioned html popoup

Comment: @Athul - Okay so are you using Bootstrap in your project?

Comment: @Rahul Singh :yes rahul

Comment: @Athul - Okay so have you tried writing the same code in the main page (i.e. where gridview is present) ? It should work as expected since the popup is on the same page and its not a different page.

Comment: @Rahul Singh:you are right,both popup and grid are on the same page.but i am not sure how to assign those values from popup text box to gridview pls help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97758/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-athul).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *jQuery* on method to bind the button click event handler and populate the textbox present inside the gridview like this:-

```
 $("#div_History").on('click','button.btn', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var firstRow = $('tr:nth-child(2)', $('#GridView1'));
       var outsideText = $('#txtOutside').val();
       $('#txtfoo', firstRow).val(outsideText);
 });
```

For safer side I have added a class to the button control. You can change it like this:-

```
<button onclick="return myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>
```