# how to update gridview textbox value in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview with 6 columns in 5th  column i have placed a text box, all the data are populating in the grid by executing stored procedure from database .

i have another textbox and ok button outside the gridview also.

> > Now i need to update the text box value in the gridview with the same text which is added to the outside the text box inside ok button click event ..

how can i do this without saving data to database?through javascript or jquery?

Comment: Post some code. Also you wanna populate the data in which row of gridview?

Comment: @RahulSingh: in first row only. But i don't know how to achieve this pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing if you are using ASP.NET 4 or above then you can set the `ClientIDMode` of your controls to **Static** so that it will be easier to work with the controls in *jQuery*. Alternatively you can also add custom attributes or class to your controls. Now since a gridview is rendered as html table in browser you can find the second row in the table (since first row is *header row*) and update the value like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault(); 
          var firstRow = $('tr:nth-child(2)', $('#GridView1'));
          var outsideText = $('#txtOutside').val();
          $('#txtfoo', firstRow).val(outsideText);
      });
}
```

Here I have considered that the ID of your gridview control is `GridView1`, the textbox which is outside is `txtOutside`, button is `btnSubmit` and the textbox which is outside is `txtOutside`.

Comment: $('#txtfoo', firstRow).val(outsideText); if i passed row index here will it work for respective rows?

Comment: @sajju - `firstRow` is only the first row. Yes if you will manipulate the _RowIndex_ in `tr:nth-child(2)` it will work for whatever row you want.

Comment: will this logic work here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224982/how-to-set-values-to-gridview-textbox-from-javascript-function

Comment: @sajju - You mean in a pop-up? rest code will remain same only you will have to access the text from the popup.

Comment: @sajju - Okay I will try if possible share the code to open the popup window.